# multilevel ExpandableListView with json parsing from URI

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to create a multilevel `ExpandableListView` with JSON parsing from URI, `ExpandableListView` values getting from URI only.

**For example:**

```
1. -->category
               1. book
                 --> 1.tamil
                        book1,
                        book2
                 --> 2.English
                        book1,
                        book2
               2.sports
                    ...
               3.education
                   ...
```

Is it possible do like this?

Please give me a solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: please give any reference or sample code @Rami

Comment: @murugananthamselvam please show us what you've tried so far and how its not working as you expect it to.

Comment: just now i searehing the example code  but i need this @AlexD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- Create your own custom `ExpandableListView` (or `ListView`)  class.
- Use a third party library like [tree-view-list-android](https://github.com/Polidea/tree-view-list-android) or [AndroidTreeView](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView).

Comment: AndroidTreeview have exactly want i want thank you@Rami

Comment: @murugananthamselvam You're welcome.

Comment: if my question is useful to others,please upvote my question @Rami